# The argument type 'AppUser? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User Function(User?)'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I get this error: `The argument type 'AppUser? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User Function(User?)'.`

I found another stackoverflow Question about this topic, but the solution doesn´t work for me

here is the part of my code where the error appears:

```
  AppUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? AppUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
```

Comment: (User user) can never be null if you don't change it for (User? user) in your "_userFromFirebaseUser" method. That right there is one of the problems in your code. You are also maping and User into an AppUser but expecting an User in return for your Stream and that's the other problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wish you explained better what you are trying to do, but here is why this piece of code doesn't work:

```
Stream<User> get user { ... }
```

The values of your stream are of type `User`.

You are trying to map each user's values using this function:

```
AppUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) { ... }
```

But that function doesn't return a `User`, it returns a `AppUser?`, very different things, you can't add a `AppUser?` to a `Stream<User>`. To fix this, change the type of your stream:

```
Stream<AppUser?> get user { ... }
```

Finally, I want you to know that `user != null ? AppUser(uid: user.uid) : null;` is redundant because `user` will **never** be null, user's type is `User` not `User?`, so you can actually completely get rid of nullable types:

```
AppUser _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
  return AppUser(uid: user.uid);
}

Stream<AppUser> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}
```

On the off chance that `user` **can** be null, you will get an error with the above code, then you actually need to do the opposite of what I did, make everything nullable:

```
AppUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
  return user == null ? null : AppUser(uid: user.uid);
}

Stream<AppUser?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}
```